# How detect iphone battery level in application running in background?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an iphone application which includes battery level tracking. The main requirement of my application is to run application in background and comes on foreground when battery level reaches to low. I knew battery level tracking in iphone is not a big task but how can i do it from the background? can it be possible to do this type of work in background. Any idea will appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do one thing. Schedule a local notification when the battery level reaches certain low limit. Once the battery reaches to that level, the notification is fired. But it will show an alert and when user clicks on it, the app will come to foreground if in background or inactive.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done only on devices which support multitasking , You  can look for more details here..

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

The page does give some info regarding performing tasks in background..